# Static member initialization using CRTP in separate library

Tags: c++, templates, design-patterns

After digging the web, I found some reference to a powerful pattern which exploits CRTP to allow instantiation at run-time of static members:

[C++: Compiling unused classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466466/c-compiling-unused-classes?lq=1)

[Initialization class for other classes - C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905527/initialization-class-for-other-classes-c/10907093#10907093)

And so on.
The proposed approach works well, unless such class hierarchy is placed into an external library.
Doing so, run-time initialization no more works, unless I manually #include somewhere the header file of derived classes. However, this defeats my main purpose - having the change to add new commands to my application without the need of changing other source files.

Some code, hoping it helps:

```
class CAction
{
protected:
    // some non relevant stuff
public:
    // some other public API
    CAction(void) {}
    virtual ~CAction(void) {}

    virtual std::wstring Name() const = 0;
};

template <class TAction>
class CCRTPAction : public CAction
{
public:
    static bool m_bForceRegistration;
    CCRTPAction(void) { m_bForceRegistration; }
    ~CCRTPAction(void) { }

    static bool init() {
        CActionManager::Instance()->Add(std::shared_ptr<CAction>(new TAction));
        return true;
    }
};

template<class TAction> bool CCRTPAction<TAction>::m_bForceRegistration = CCRTPAction<TAction>::init();
```

Implementations being done this way:

```
class CDummyAction : public CCRTPAction<CDummyAction>
{
public:
    CDummyAction() { }
    ~CDummyAction() { }
    std::wstring Name() const { return L"Dummy"; }
};
```

Finally, here is the container class API:

```
class CActionManager
{
private:
    CActionManager(void);
    ~CActionManager(void);
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<CAction>> m_vActions;   
    static CActionManager* instance;
public:
    void Add(std::shared_ptr<CAction>& Action);
    const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<CAction>>& AvailableActions() const;
    static CActionManager* Instance() {
        if (nullptr == instance) {
            instance = new CActionManager();
        }
        return instance;
    }
};
```

Everything works fine in a single project solution. However, if I place the above code in a separate .lib, the magic somehow breaks and the implementation classes (`DummyAction` and so on) are no longer instantiated.

I see that `#include "DummyAction.h"` somewhere, either in my library or in the main project makes things work, but

1. For our project, it is mandatory that adding Actions does not require changes in other files.
2. I don't really understand what's happening behind the scene, and this makes me uncomfortable. I really hate depending on solutions I don't fully master, since a bug could get out anywhere, anytime, possibly one day before shipping our software to the customer :)
3. Even stranger, putting the `#include` directive but not defining constructor/destructor in the header file still breaks the magic.

Thanks all for attention. I really hope someone is able to shed some light...

Comment: @Tony The Lion I can see legit use-cases of this! Generally it should be avoided, but sometimes it's the best option. And the above code does not violate good software writing practices.

Comment: I only know of one legit singleton use case, that is a logger type object.  I know of no legit use case for manager classes, that's just plain bad design.

Comment: @RalphTandetzky it uses Singletons, "let's try expanding this code... oh, can't without rewriting most of it". It uses classes named 'manager'... and it does what? Manage? what is that exactly? What do I need this class for?

Comment: This is a perfectly valid question - the singleton debate belongs in chat.

Comment: I believe this occurs because the linker thinks the code is not referenced. Which compiler are you using? You could try some different compiler options to test this hypothesis: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16294842/how-to-disable-c-dead-code-stripping-in-xcode

Comment: Compiler is MSVC++12. The objects are not required to be singleton (debate is still ongoing, we are at the very beginning of the design phase and I tried to lay out some code to bring out unforeseen issues), what is required - by now - is that at least one instance can be accessed by a single central repository, without the need for the repository to know all the classes and allowing the coders to just add the .h/.cpp files without need to modify other code.

Comment: Have you tried using a .dll instead of a .lib? I remember it "fixed" the problem for me a while ago, although I cannot confirm it is reliable. According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/78235/420683) it is reliable.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I'd like to avoid dlls, since the code will make heavy use of template code and API is goingo to be quite complex. However, I'll keep it in mind.

Comment: A DLL linked at load-time (via a dummy .lib) is used like a static .lib, no changes are required IIRC. (As opposed to run-time linking via `LoadModule`, `GetProcAddress` etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in Mike's answer, the compiler determines that the static member `CCRTPAction<CDummyAction>::m_bForceRegistration` is never used, and therefore does not need to be initialised.

The problem you're trying to solve is to initialise a set of 'plugin' modules without having to `#include` their code in a central location. CTRP and templates will not help you here. I'm not aware of a (portable) way in C++ to generate code to initialise a set of plugin modules that are not referenced from main().

If you're willing to make the (reasonable) concession of having to list the plugin modules in a central location (without including their headers), there's a simple solution. I believe this is one of those extremely rare cases where a function-scope `extern` declaration is useful. You may consider this a dirty hack, but when there's no other way, a dirty hack becomes an elegant solution ;).

This code compiles to the main executable:

`core/module.h`

```
template<void (*init)()>
struct Module
{
    Module()
    {
        init();
    }
};

// generates: extern void initDummy(); Module<initDummy> DummyInstance
#define MODULE_INSTANCE(name) \
    extern void init ## name(); \
    Module<init ## name> name ## Instance
```

`core/action.h`

```
struct Action // an abstract action
{
};

void addAction(Action& action); // adds the abstract action to a list
```

`main.cpp`

```
#include "core/module.h"

int main()
{
    MODULE_INSTANCE(Dummy);
}
```

This code implements the `Dummy` module and compiles to a separate library:

`dummy/action.h`

```
#include "core/action.h"

struct DummyAction : Action // a concrete action
{
};
```

`dummy/init.cpp`

```
#include "action.h"

void initDummy()
{
    addAction(*new DummyAction());
}
```

If you wanted to go further (this part is not portable) you could write a separate program to generate a list of `MODULE_INSTANCE` calls, one for each module in your application, and output a generated header file:

`generated/init.h`

```
#include "core/module.h"

#define MODULE_INSTANCES \
    MODULE_INSTANCE(Module1); \
    MODULE_INSTANCE(Module2); \
    MODULE_INSTANCE(Module3);
```

Add this as a pre-build step, and `core/main.cpp` becomes:

```
#include "generated/init.h"

int main()
{
    MODULE_INSTANCES
}
```

If you later decide to load some or all of these modules dynamically, you can use **exactly** the same pattern to dynamically load, initialise and unload a dll. Please note that the following example is windows-specific, untested and does not handle errors:

`core/dynamicmodule.h`

```
struct DynamicModule
{
    HMODULE dll;

    DynamicModule(const char* filename, const char* init)
    {
        dll = LoadLibrary(filename);
        FARPROC function = GetProcAddress(dll, init);
        function();
    }
    ~DynamicModule()
    {
        FreeLibrary(dll);
    }
};

#define DYNAMICMODULE_INSTANCE(name) \
    DynamicModule name ## Instance = DynamicModule(#name ".dll", "init" #name)
```

Comment: Thanks for your patience @willj, your proposal is working and I'm going to accept your answer. Just one more clarification - why is the MODULE_INSTANCES snippet not portable?

Comment: Writing a separate program and adding it as a pre-build step would require some platform/build-system specific changes. Perhaps it would be better to say that it's not pure C++.

Answer (score 4):

I can describe the cause of the problem; unfortunately I can't offer a solution.

The problem is that initialisation of a variable with static storage duration may be deferred until any time before the first use of something defined *in the same translation unit*. If your program never uses anything in the same translation unit as `CCRTPAction<CDummyAction>::m_bForceRegistration`, then that variable may never be initialised.

As you found, including the header in the translation unit that defines `main` will force it to be initialised at some point before the start of `main`; but of course that solution won't meet your first requirement. My usual solution to the problems of initialising static data across multiple translation units is to avoid static data altogether (and the Singleton anti-pattern doubly so, although that's the least of your problems here).

Comment: Thanks for clarification, Mike. I'm ashamed I cannot vote up your answer, since it has been of great help, my reputation score is still too low ...

Answer (score 1):

As Mike Seymour stated the static template stuff will not give you the dynamic loading facilities you want. You could load your modules dynamically as plug ins. Put dlls containing an action each into the working directory of the application and load these dlls dynamically at run-time. This way you will not have to change your source code in order to use different or new implementations of `CAction`.

Some frameworks make it easy to load custom plug ins, [for example Qt](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/plugins-howto.html).

Comment: What about a single dll containing all the actions?
BTW the actions are going to make use of template code, I found that exposing templates on a dll inteface is less than ideal. Is it going to work also with static libraries?

Comment: A single dll containing all actions will do as well. And yes templates and dlls don't work well at all. Avoid it. It will probably work with static libraries, if you make sure the classes get instantiated somewhere within the static library. Defining member functions such as constructors and destructors seems to work for that purpose.

Comment: templates and dlls work fine, provided that you build all the dlls from exactly the same source. If you can do that, the remaining complication is that global static objects are not shared between dlls.

Comment: this is likely, but not guaranteed for the future. Therefore, I would better follow willj's advice by now. Thanks all for pointing out this anyway, it will likely help in further phases of the project.

By the way, what about dynamically allocated resources passed across DLL boundaries? I know that this can also be an issue, is it mitigated by having the whole solution come from the same source?